# Unable to get object data(string) in Chrome console log

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object list in JavaScript, I want to get and parse "total" in a variable. But whenever I print or filter in console log, it always give null value.

```
var dd = result1[0] // orignal data
console.log(typeof dd) // this is object
console.log(dd); // this printing whole object list

// try 1
console.log(JSON.stringify(dd));

// try 2
for (const key in dd) {
if (dd.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${dd[key]}`);
    }
}
```

[image]

I tried `JSON.stringify(dd)`, but nothing worked.

Comment: how does `result1[0]` looks like

Comment: What is result1.

Comment: console.log(dd.total); // this should get the total value according to image description

Comment: There is probably some asynchronous code involved, calculating that `total` and you are not awaiting it properly. `console.log` can be deceiving

Comment: @derpirscher doesn't even have to be asynchronous. The typical example of this behaviour is `const obj = { foo: 1 }; console.log(obj, obj.foo); obj.foo = 2;` where the code is fully synchronous but the value you would see after expanding the object in the console is `2` not `1`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, you are right. But the typical case when one expects a variable or property to have a value at some point in the code, but it doesn't, is, that it's calculated asynchronously and not awaited properly

Comment: I have already tried console.log(dd.total); , but ERROR total not found.

Comment: result1 also have same structure just add 2 value, so I used 0 index to get first.